# Как использовать QHoverEvent?

Tags: c++, qt

В документации об этом мало что написано, поэтому и возник вопрос. Срабатывает ли это событие для обычных виджетов? Чем оно отличается от `mouseMoveEvent`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В официальной [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qhoverevent.html) все прекрасно описано.

Да, это событие срабатывает для обычных виджетов. Отличие от `MouseMove` заключается в том, что событие `MouseHover` могут получать родительские виджеты когда они перекрыты дочерними виджетами. Тогда как `MouseMove` получает только один виджет над которым перемещается курсор мыши.

Comment: Это событие срабатывает даже если виджет перекрыт окном? И как переопределить это событие, как называются методы этого события? Аналогичные `mouseMoveEvent();`

Comment: @Nik Наверно обработать, а не переопределить? Любое событие Qt вы можете обработать в виртуальной функции `event` реализация по-умолчанию которой как раз и вызывает все специализированные обработчики, подобные `mouseMoveEvent`.

Comment: Хорошо, я пробовал в виртуальной функции `event();` поставить `switch` и если тип события `hoverevent` делать какие-то действия, но это событие не срабатывало, если виджет перекрывается другим виджетом/окном, хотя вы говорили, должно.

Comment: @Nik Я писал не должно, а может! Попробуйте сделать `widget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoMousePropagation, false)`.

Comment: @Nik Уточнил ответ.

Comment: Ах вот оно что, виджет должен быть родителем, чтобы получать события... А нет такого, чтобы получать события даже если виджет перекрыт окном/другим виджетом? Я просто хочу узнать, что во время перетаскивания одного окна, курсор мыши попал на виджет в другом окне. Или сделать невидимым окно для событий(чтобы для механизма событий окна как-бы не существовало)?

Comment: @Nik Это уже другой вопрос, лучше задать его отдельно. Ну а так, попробуйте, например, [eventFilter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html)